# Picture Puzzle: Spaces/Gaps between Grid Rows

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid

I try to code a little Picture Puzzle for a family party in some weeks.

The puzzle should look like this: http://www.welt.de/spiele/online-spiele/article2128160/Bilderraetsel.html
(just press "Spiel starten" for a demo)

I know that my solution now is very slow and ugly.. but as a first step it's working.

I create a lot of rectangles dynamically depending on the size of the image (and this is important because I will use the puzzle for different images).

Then, every X seconds one rectangle will get invisibility (opacity step change to 0).

The problem is, in the application there are spaces between the rectangle rows.

I tried it with StackPanel, WrapPanel and UniformGrid. With UniformGrid I got the best results.

The best would be if I would generate a gray image over the whole size of the picture in memory and cut some rectangles away in my timer from this memory image. But I like the opacity effect, and so it's not possible, or is it?

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="PicturePuzzle.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="420"
        Loaded="WindowLoaded">
  <Grid>
    <Grid Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <Image x:Name="imgPicture"
             Source="/PicturePuzzle;component/Images/Koala.jpg"
             Stretch="Uniform" />
      <UniformGrid x:Name="ugMask"
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=imgPicture,
                                   Path=ActualWidth}"
                   Height="{Binding ElementName=imgPicture,
                                    Path=ActualHeight}" />

    </Grid>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
      <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnStart"
                Width="60"
                Margin="0,0,5,0"
                Click="BtnStartClick"
                Content="Start" />
        <Button x:Name="btnStop"
                Width="60"
                Click="BtnStopClick"
                Content="Stop"
                IsEnabled="False" />
        <Button x:Name="btnSolution"
                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                Click="BtnSolutionClick"
                Content="Lösung anzeigen" />
      </StackPanel>
      <Slider x:Name="slSpeed"
              IsDirectionReversed="True"
              Maximum="10"
              Minimum="1"
              ValueChanged="SlSpeedValueChanged"
              Value="3" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And my codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace PicturePuzzle
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      _rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

      InitializeComponent();

      _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
      _generated = new List<int>();
      _random = new Random();
    }

    private readonly List<Rectangle> _rectangles;
    private readonly List<int> _generated;
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;
    private readonly Random _random;

    private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var size = imgPicture.RenderSize;

      var columns = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(size.Width/20));
      var rows = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(size.Height/20));

      ugMask.Columns = columns;
      ugMask.Rows = rows;

      for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
      {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
        {
          var rectangle = new Rectangle {Width = 20, Height = 20, Fill = Brushes.Gray};

          _rectangles.Add(rectangle);

          ugMask.Children.Add(rectangle);
        }
      }
    }

    private void BtnStartClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      btnStart.IsEnabled = false;
      btnStop.IsEnabled = true;

      _generated.Clear();
      _rectangles.ForEach(a => a.Opacity = 1);

      _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(slSpeed.Value);
      _timer.Tick += TimerTick;
      _timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (_generated.Count >= _rectangles.Count)
      {
        _timer.Stop();
        return;
      }

      var random = GetNext();

      var alphaTimer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)};

      alphaTimer.Tick += (o, args) =>
        {
          var rec = _rectangles[random];

          if (rec.Opacity <= 0)
          {
            alphaTimer.Stop();
            return;
          }

          rec.Opacity -= 0.1;
        };

      alphaTimer.Start();
    }

    private int GetNext()
    {
      int r;

      do
      {
        r = _random.Next(0, _rectangles.Count);
      } while (_generated.Contains(r));


      _generated.Add(r);

      return r;
    }

    private void BtnStopClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
      btnStop.IsEnabled = false;

      _timer.Stop();
    }

    private void SlSpeedValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
      if (_timer != null)
      {
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((slSpeed.Value / 10));
      }
    }

    private void BtnSolutionClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      btnStop.IsEnabled = false;
      btnStart.IsEnabled = true;

      _timer.Stop();

      _rectangles.ForEach(a => a.Opacity = 0);
    }
  }
}
```

And here you can see the produced result:

[image: Picture Puzzle]

Every hint is welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of testing, and you actually have two problems.

First, the rectangles are being antialiased.  (This is the WPF default.) You will need to turn antialiasing off for the rectangles to get the edges to line up.  Add the following line, after you create the rectangle:

`rectangle.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);`

Second, if the width of koala.jpg, after it is uniformly stretched to a height of 300, is not a multiple of 20, then the 20 x 20 rectangles, uniformly spaced, would have to have gaps in between.  The gaps in your result are due to the rounding error when rows is rounded and cast to an int32.

You have two options:

If you don't mind squishing the image a little, you can set the width of the Grid element to a multiple of 20.  Then set the Stretch property of the Image tag to "Fill".  This would keep your rectangles exactly square.

You could also set the width of your rectangles to `size.Width / columns`  This would stretch them a little so that they fit exactly.  For good measure, you could also set their height to `size.Height / rows`.  Because `size.Width` and `size.Height` are floating point numbers, this divide will correct for the rounding error when rows and columns were calculated.  This would allow arbitrarily sized images, but your rectangles wouldn't be exactly square.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason, but how can I avoid this issue? I tried to set width and height to something like 22, but that didnt change anything.

Comment: the second way will produce the same result, because I calculate the columns: `var columns = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(size.Width/20));`

Comment: It won't give the same number because when you round up and cast to an int32, you lose any decimal places in your answer.  By dividing width and height by the columns and rows (using floating point math), you end up calculating this rounding error.

Comment: I tried out your code and found a second issue causing the problem.  By default, WPF antialiases everything, which causes the edges of things to be semitransparent.  I updated my answer with a solution to this.

Comment: Hey, thanks, for this I think this would be the solution.. But I changed the way to generate my mask and my new question is located here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497896/picture-puzzle-set-one-image-to-the-same-size-and-position-to-another-image