# Picture Puzzle: Set one Image to the same size and position to another image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, grid

today I already asked you a question for my picture puzzle ([Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488809/picture-puzzle-spaces-gaps-between-grid-rows/13488942)).

I started to rewrite my code for better performance. And I got the most important part done!

But I have another problem.. I generate a gray overlay image to hide the image, but because I want to handle dynamic size of pictures I cannot set fixed width and height values for the "mask". So probably not the whole picture is overlayed with my "mask".

Does somebody have a solution for this? I don't know how to set the position and size of my mask exactly to the position and size of the picture.

I attached a screencast for demonstration.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="PicturePuzzle.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Loaded="WindowLoaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="grid"
              Margin="5"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Top">

            <Image x:Name="imgPicture"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Source="Images/puzzle.gif"
                   Stretch="Uniform" />
            <Image x:Name="imgMask" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="btnStart"
                        Width="60"
                        Margin="0,0,5,0"
                        Click="BtnStartClick"
                        Content="Start" />
                <Button x:Name="btnStop"
                        Width="60"
                        Click="BtnStopClick"
                        Content="Stop"
                        IsEnabled="False" />
                <ToggleButton x:Name="btnSolution"
                              Margin="5,0,0,0"
                              Checked="btnSolution_Checked"
                              Content="Lösung anzeigen"
                              Unchecked="btnSolution_Unchecked" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Slider x:Name="slSpeed"
                    IsDirectionReversed="True"
                    Maximum="10"
                    Minimum="1"
                    ValueChanged="SlSpeedValueChanged"
                    Value="10" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace PicturePuzzle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _positionAlphaValues = new Dictionary<Point, byte>();

            _images = new List<FileInfo>();
            using (var s = new StreamReader("Images.txt"))
            {
                while (!s.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = s.ReadLine();

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var fi = new FileInfo(line);

                    if (!fi.Exists)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    _images.Add(fi);
                }
            }
        }

        private const int MaxQuadsX = 5;
        private const int MaxQuadsY = 5;

        private readonly List<FileInfo> _images;

        private DispatcherTimer _timer;
        private DispatcherTimer _alphaTimer;
        private WriteableBitmap _bitmap;
        private Size _size;
        private List<Point> _positions;
        private Dictionary<Point, byte> _positionAlphaValues;
        private int _tickCounter;
        private int _imageCounter;
        private int _quadWidth;
        private int _quadHeight;


        private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _size = imgPicture.RenderSize;

            var width = (int)Math.Ceiling(_size.Width);
            var height = (int)Math.Ceiling(_size.Height);

            _quadWidth = width / MaxQuadsX;
            _quadHeight = height / MaxQuadsY;

            imgPicture.Width = _quadWidth * MaxQuadsX - 5;
            imgPicture.Height = _quadHeight * MaxQuadsY - 5;

            _bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);

            imgMask.Source = _bitmap;
        }

        #region Click handlers

        private void BtnStartClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.IsEnabled = false;
            btnStop.IsEnabled = true;
            btnSolution.IsChecked = false;

            // set the real picture
            _imageCounter = 0;
            _images.Shuffle();
            SetPuzzlePicture();

            _timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(slSpeed.Value / 10) };
            _timer.Tick += TimerTick;
            _timer.Start();

            _alphaTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1) };
            _alphaTimer.Tick += AlphaTimerOnTick;
            _alphaTimer.Start();
        }

        private void BtnStopClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
            btnStop.IsEnabled = false;

            _timer.Stop();
            _alphaTimer.Stop();
        }

        private void SlSpeedValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            if (_timer != null)
            {
                _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(slSpeed.Value / 10);
            }
        }


        private void btnSolution_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnStop.IsEnabled = false;

            StopTimers();

            imgMask.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        private void btnSolution_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
            btnStop.IsEnabled = false;

            ResetMaskImage();
        }

        #endregion

        private void SetPuzzlePicture()
        {
            _positionAlphaValues.Clear();

            ResetMaskImage();

            var imgFile = _images[_imageCounter++];

            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.UriSource = new Uri(imgFile.FullName, UriKind.Absolute);
            image.EndInit();

            imgPicture.Source = image;
        }

        private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_tickCounter >= _positions.Count)
            {
                if (_imageCounter >= _images.Count)
                {
                    _timer.Stop();

                    btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
                    btnStop.IsEnabled = false;

                    return;
                }

                SetPuzzlePicture();
            }

            var randomPoint = _positions[_tickCounter++];

            _positionAlphaValues.Add(randomPoint, 255);
        }

        private void AlphaTimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var updatedList = new Dictionary<Point, byte>();

            foreach (var e in _positionAlphaValues)
            {
                var newValue = e.Value - (11 - slSpeed.Value) * 5;

                if (newValue <= 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                SetAlphaChannel(e.Key, (byte)newValue);
                updatedList.Add(e.Key, (byte)newValue);
            }

            _positionAlphaValues = updatedList;
        }

        private void StopTimers()
        {
            if (_timer != null)
            {
                _timer.Stop();
            }

            if (_alphaTimer != null)
            {
                _alphaTimer.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void ResetMaskImage()
        {
            imgMask.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            var width = _quadWidth * MaxQuadsX;
            var height = _quadHeight * MaxQuadsY;
            var size = width * height * 4;

            var buffer = new byte[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                buffer[i++] = 128;
                buffer[i++] = 128;
                buffer[i++] = 128;
                buffer[i] = 255;
            }

            var area = new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height);
            _bitmap.WritePixels(area, buffer, width * 4, 0);

            _positions = GetPositions();
            _tickCounter = 0;
        }

        private void SetAlphaChannel(Point point, byte alpha)
        {
            var size = _quadWidth * _quadHeight * 4;
            var buffer = new byte[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                buffer[i++] = 128;
                buffer[i++] = 128;
                buffer[i++] = 128;
                buffer[i] = alpha;
            }

            var startX = (int)point.X * _quadWidth;
            var startY = (int)point.Y * _quadHeight;

            var area = new Int32Rect(startX, startY, _quadWidth, _quadHeight);
            _bitmap.WritePixels(area, buffer, _quadWidth * 4, 0);
        }

        private List<Point> GetPositions()
        {
            var generated = new List<Point>();

            for (int y = 0; y < MaxQuadsY; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < MaxQuadsX; x++)
                {
                    var point = new Point(x, y);

                    generated.Add(point);
                }
            }

            generated.Shuffle();

            return generated;
        }
    }
}
```

Extensions.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace PicturePuzzle
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Color GetPixel(this WriteableBitmap wbm, int x, int y)
        {
            if (y > wbm.PixelHeight - 1 || x > wbm.PixelWidth - 1)
                return Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

            if (y < 0 || x < 0)
                return Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

            if (!wbm.Format.Equals(PixelFormats.Bgra32))
                return Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

            IntPtr buff = wbm.BackBuffer;
            int stride = wbm.BackBufferStride;
            Color c;

            unsafe
            {
                var pbuff = (byte*)buff.ToPointer();
                int loc = y * stride + x * 4;

                c = Color.FromArgb(
                  pbuff[loc + 3],
                  pbuff[loc + 2], pbuff[loc + 1],
                  pbuff[loc]);
            }

            return c;
        }

        public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            int n = list.Count;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
                T value = list[k];
                list[k] = list[n];
                list[n] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example Images.txt (has to be in your output folder, the images also):

```
Desert.jpg
Hydrangeas.jpg
Jellyfish.jpg
Koala.jpg
Lighthouse.jpg
Penguins.jpg
Tulips.jpg
androids.gif
Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

And the screencast: [Screencast Link](http://screencast.com/t/Ktunt0lRb3)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` of your mask Image to `Stretch` and the `Stretch` to Fill like so:

`<Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="imgMask" Stretch="Fill" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />`

This will cause the mask image to fill the grid, which will be sized to the other image.

Comment: Hey, the mask now has the whole size of the grid / window (expect of the 80 pixels controlbar on the bottom, but thats exactly what I want). But the imgPicture does not have the same size and is not resizing. Tried it with setting Stretch to Fill and Uniform for imgPicture. The best solution would be, if the Mask would have exactly the dimensions of the imgPicture with Stretch="Uniform".